# Why do some picklists (dropdowns) have an empty --None-- value, and others do not?

Tags: custom-object, picklist

I'm looking at a form on Salesforce that uses a custom object. The object has picklist (drop down) values that are showing an optional --None-- selection. Most of the drop downs have the --None-- selection available, but some do not. Where would I configure a picklist to have (or not have) a --None-- selection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a picklist field is marked as required (e.g. in the layout), and the picklist field already has a non-null value the "--None--" value is not presented. The non-null value cases are:

- on a "New" page where the picklist defaults to the first value
- on an "Edit" page where a value has already been entered

There is no explicit setting on the picklist itself.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using the REST API, and the --None-- values do not come down. I'll have to manually add them based on your conditions I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

A less likely, but possible, explanation is that on a VF page, the picklists could be generated from controller properties into apex:selectOptions. Unless the controller explicitly inserts a selectOption with value `-- None --`, the picklist will not appear with any `-- None --` option

Answer (score 0):

I follwed this thread and wanted to make my dependent picklist to remove the none value but it didn't work. My picklist field is dependent with opportunity stage.
Everytime i click on my picklist field, it is presented to me with None value as well.

I already made the picklist as required in page layout and also defaulted a picklist value.